# How do I get the dates when people were absent?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have the following table called **employees**:

| num_employee | name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | George |
| 002 | Mary |

And the table called **records**:

| num_employee | date |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-12-01 |
| 002 | 2021-12-01 |
| 001 | 2021-12-02 |
| 002 | 2021-12-01 |
| 001 | 2021-12-03 |
| 002 | 2021-12-06 |
| 002 | 2021-12-07 |

The **records** table contains the employee's number along with the date they have an attendance; what I would like to get are the days in which the employees were absent (which are the dates that the **records** table does not contain).

In the example above, both employees attended on December 1st and 2nd; Mary was absent on day 03 and George was absent on days 06 and 07. Days 04 and 05 were weekends, so they are not considered absences since they are non-working days (working days are from Monday to Friday).

What I am looking for is to obtain a result in which the employee number is displayed, his name and the day of the month which he was absent:

| num_employee | name | absent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | George | 6,7 |
| 002 | Mary | 3 |

I have a table containing all the dates of the month, called **dates**:

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 |
| 2 | 2021-12-02 |
| 3 | 2021-12-03 |
| 4 | 2021-12-04 |
| 5 | 2021-12-05 |
| 6 | 2021-12-06 |
| 7 | 2021-12-07 |

And the only thing I have achieved is to develop this query, which assigns the days of the month to each user, but it needs to make the comparison with the **records** table in order to only show the days on which there was absence:

```
SELECT u.num_employee, u.name, d.date FROM employees e
JOIN
(SELECT date FROM dates) d
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT num_employee, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT( DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM records WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-07' GROUP BY num_employee) r
ON e.num_employee = r.num_employee
```

With the above query I get the following:

| num_employee | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | George | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |
| 002 | Mary | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |

How can I adapt my query to stop requiring filtering by employee and display them all with their respective dates when they were absent?

I am working with MariaDB in phpMyAdmin. CTE does not work for me with the version I am working on.

In this example I'm only cosidering the first week of December.

Comment: you also need to have a table of non-working days of a month, say, nwdays, then you may use the query: select date from dates where date not in (select date from nwdays) a and date not in (select date from records where num_employee='001') b

Comment: @Shiping, I want to display all employees with one query, not one employee per query

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from employees e
cross join dates d
left join records r
    on r.num_employee = e.num_employee
    and r.date = d.date
where r.num_employee is null
```